# How to change with js / jquery attribute onkeyup with another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change value of HTML onkeyup attribute with js/jquery?

Comment: read this: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

You can modify an attribute of an HTML element using [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

```js
function red() {
  document.body.style.background = "red";
}

function green() {
  document.body.style.background = "green";
}

function change() {
  document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("onkeyup", "green()");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="change()">Test</button><br />
<input id="test" onkeyup="red()" />
```

Comment: Well, that's a good answer (Though you didn't explain to the OP how to test it) but if this tagged under jQuery than perhaps it would be better to show how to do it the jQuery without using event attributes (Just a suggestion, this answer is still good)